# jekyll/octopress embedded youtube videos caching issue

Tags: youtube, jekyll, octopress

I have an octopress site http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/  that embeds different screencasts from youtube.  The correct video is displayed when the site is initially loaded, however, when a particular post is selected and one goes back from the browser all of the embedded videos point to the same single video.

I'm hosting the pages on github and I can't figure out why the pages are I think being cached in this way.  Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem you described for your site.

But You might want to add `<!--more-->` before your videos so that videos are not shown in the blog list page. All these videos made the page loading a bit slow, which kinda defeat the purpose of using static page.